Obtaining fill with FMX.Objects.TPath mixed drawing order
When drawing with Firemonkey FMX.Objects.TPath, I want to draw in a mixed drawing order. The drawing fill must be painted correctly.
How can I do that?
(The drawings come in mixed order. Putting these in order is a very complicated task.)
I just need to solve it with TPath drawing. Painting with Image, Bitmap is not the right result for me.
I want to give some information.
When drawing with Firemonkey FMX.Objects.TPath, there are some rules for automatically painting the inside of the drawing.

The drawing should continue in the form of a chain. In this way, the drawing fill is painted correctly.

Even if the drawing order is correct, the drawing direction must also be correct.


3)There should be no "MoveTo" between the ongoing drawing. In this way, only lines are drawn. The inside of the square is not colored with the fill color.
1 correct, 3 incorrect examples. Can I get correct painting on incorrect drawings?

begin
//Accurate drawing, chain drawing, closed drawing, accurate painting
Path1.Data.MoveTo(PointF(0, 0));
Path1.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 0));
Path1.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 50));
Path1.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 50));
Path1.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 0));

//Although the drawing order is correct, the drawing appears open due to unnecessary use of moveto between lines, incorrect result
Path2.Data.MoveTo(PointF(0, 0));
Path2.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 0));
Path2.Data.MoveTo(PointF(50, 0));
Path2.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 50));
Path2.Data.MoveTo(PointF(50, 50));
Path2.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 50));
Path2.Data.MoveTo(PointF(0, 50));
Path2.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 0));

//Drawing order incorrect, incorrect result
Path3.Data.MoveTo(PointF(0, 0));
Path3.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 0));
Path3.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 50));
Path3.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 50));
Path3.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 0));

//Drawing order incorrect, incorrect result
Path4.Data.MoveTo(PointF(0, 0));
Path4.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 0));
Path4.Data.MoveTo(PointF(50, 0));
Path4.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 50));
Path4.Data.MoveTo(PointF(0, 50));
Path4.Data.LineTo(PointF(50, 50));
Path4.Data.MoveTo(PointF(50, 50));
Path4.Data.LineTo(PointF(0, 0));
end;

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Objects.TPath
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Graphics.TPathData.LineTo
Edit 1:
I would like to add some more explanation.
I need to read the DXF file and draw it in the TPath object with my application.
+I'm reading the DXF file. Read(Line, Arc, Circle, Ellipse, Point etc...)
+I can draw the drawing I read in TPath.
(MoveTo, LineTo, AddArc...)
The problem I have is that in DXF drawings, the drawings are generally not drawn in a chained order. If the drawing is not drawn in a chained order, when I transfer the drawing to the TPath object, the object is not filled automatically.
How can I fix the drawing before passing it to the TPath Object for autofill to be applied? Is there a way for this?


If your third example is incorrect, what should it look like?

Your second shape can be drawn exactly as the first one was, so there's no issue there.  And the fourth can be drawn exactly as the third was, so there's no issue there either. What specifically is the problem you're trying to solve here?

I don't understand what you are asking. You say: I want to draw in a mixed drawing order. But you have already found out that drawing takes place in the order in which the points are fed to the path. Ergo, you must feed the points in the correct order. So, what are you actually asking? What algorithm should the drawing follow, if not the order of the points?

@PhilipJ.Rayment The first example with the blue fill is correct. In the second way, the drawing is correct, but the autofill did not work. Because unnecessary moveto commands were used.
I made an addition. Please review.

@KenWhite All shapes should look like the first shape. The second figure is correct, but because unnecessary moveto was used, the drawing looks "open" and the autofill did not work. (Actually, the drawing technique of the 3rd and 4th figures is wrong. I included the drawing technique as an example.)
I made an addition. Please review.

@TomBrunberg I do not draw the drawing that comes to me. I'm just transforming the drawing. The drawing comes in DXF format. The drawing is not always drawn in the correct order as in the first example. The drawing is sometimes drawn in a mixed order. Autofill does not work for drawings drawn in mixed order. If the drawing comes in mixed order, I need to use "moveto" at the beginning of each line and as in the second example, the lines are drawn but the autofill does not work.
I made an addition. Please review.

So is your question really one of how to convert .dxf drawings to a TPath?

@PhilipJ.Rayment The problem is that the lines must be drawn consecutively. When drawing a square, if we first draw the bottom line, then the top line, and then the side lines, the TPath object does not automatically paint the inside of the piece. When drawing a square, the lines must be consecutive. It's like drawing a square on a piece of paper without raising your hand. If we draw the square like this, the TPath object will automatically paint the inside of the square. (Not just square. More complex drawings are available.)

@PhilipJ.Rayment In the drawing, I need to convert the mixed lines into consecutive order. (Or another solution that allows automatic painting inside the drawing is required.)

What about reading in a list of the lines, pick one to start with, then find the line that starts or finishes at the finish point of that one, and if it finishes with that point, swap the start and end points of that line, and repeat until all the lines have been accounted for?  Would that work, or are there scenarios that wouldn't handle?
